# Programmatically get manifestPlaceholders

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to read manifestPlaceholders' values in my code.
I found some code but they always return null.

My gradle is:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.some.test"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        manifestPlaceholders = [app_id: "xxx123"]
    }
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [app_id: "xxx123"]
    }
}
}
```

I found this code in Onesignal SDK to read values from gradle but it doesn't work:

```
    try {
        ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
        appId = bundle.getString("app_id");
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With this code, the bundle should contain manifestPlaceholders values, but it is always null.

what is the problem?

Comment: In your manifest, set up a `<meta-data>` element where the name is `app_id` and the value is your placeholder. Then your Java code should work.

Comment: I don't want to do it if you see the onesignal SDK, there is nothing in manifest @CommonsWare

Comment: Their SDK probably has that `<meta-data>` element in their manifest. Check the "Merged Manifest" tab in your Android Studio manifest editor. Or, use `buildConfigField` or `resValue` to inject data into the app from Gradle, rather than manifest placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get programmatically from your class file (java/kotlin). As –
CommonsWare suggested in comment you rather use buildConfigField or resValue to inject data into the app from Gradle.